# A Function about Removing Vowels Compile Error

Tags: c++, function

So I was writing a function to remove all the vowels in a string, and I kept getting this error:

```
pa07.cpp:138:39: error: non-const lvalue reference to type     'std::string'
(aka 'basic_string<char>') cannot bind to a value of unrelated type
'const char [12]'
cout << csutilities::removeVowels("Hello wOrld") << endl;
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
pa07.cpp:110:39: note: passing argument to parameter 'str' here
std::string removeVowels(std::string& str)
```

I don't really understand it, if anyone could explain it, so I won't do it again, that would be amazing. Thanks for any help!

```
std::string removeVowels(std::string& str)
{
    string newWord = "";

    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++)
    {
        if (str[x] == ('A') || str[x] == ('a') ||
            str[x] == ('E') || str[x] == ('e') ||
            str[x] == ('I') || str[x] == ('i') ||
            str[x] == ('O') || str[x] == ('o') ||
            str[x] == ('U') || str[x] == ('u'))
            newWord = newWord + "";
        else
            newWord = newWord + str[x];
    }//for statement to determine vowel
    return newWord;
}//function to remove vowels
```

Should just remove the vowels in a string, thanks for your time.

Comment: `removeVowels(std::string& str)` ==> `removeVowels(std::string str)`.  or `removeVowels(const std::string& str)` .Frankly, it isn't clear why you would pass that by non-const reference, i.e. why you went out of your way to specify `std::string&` explicitly, and if you pass by value (the first option), you can use the remove/erase idiom directly on the argument and not construct another string.

Comment: or to `removeVowels(const std::string &str)`.   The `const` is necessary since passing a string literal involves constructing a temporary of type `std::string` from the string literal.

Comment: Thanks I 'm good now, but I was wondering if there's a way to mark this as solved? lmao

Comment: Someone would need to make their comment the answer and you accept it. You can write the answer too (if there's no reputation limit) and accept it, but it's awkward if the answer isn't really yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
csutilities::removeVowels("Hello wOrld");
```

is equivalent to:

```
csutilities::removeVowels(std::string("Hello wOrld"))
```

The string literal gets implicitly converted to `std::string` by creating a temporary object. Temporary objects can't be passed to functions taking non-const references.

You have a few options to solve this:

1. You never modify `str` so just make it `const`.
2. If you wanted to modify `str` but the caller doesn't need to know you've changed it simply remove the reference, the `str` in the function will then be a copy of the original string
3. If you want to keep `str` as a non-const reference then you need to create a non-temporary object to pass to `removeVowels`. e.g.:

   ```
   std::string str("Hello wOrld");
   csutilities::removeVowels(str);
   ```